# Как проверить создана папка или это ошибка на самом деле?

Tags: c++, winapi

Код находится внутри цикла, мне нужно создать несколько папок, одни могут быть уже созданы а другие нет, как понять создана папка или это на самом деле ошибка.
Проблема в том, что код пишет об ошибки даже если папка уже существует, из-за этого проверка на ошибку просто бесполезна.

```
if ((SHCreateDirectory(nullptr, folderName.c_str())) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // либо создан либо ошибка, не знаю как проверить ошибка или создан
}
else
{
    wcout << folderName << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: SHCreateDirectory возвращает ERROR_SUCCESS в случае успешного создания, если каталог уже существует, то функция вернет код ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS подробнее тут, секция Return Value https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shcreatedirectory

Comment: просто смотри значение ошибки...

Comment: @goldstar_labs А как нужно написать, надо добавить еще одну проверку внутри или как?
Вы можете написать в ответе, я галочку поставлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте std::filesystem (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

```
    std::filesystem::path dir{folderName.c_str()};

    // проверка на наличие файла
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(dir)) {
        std::cout << "No file - " << dir.filename() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Я поначалу его использовал, но потом решил убрать, не знаю почему, наверно потому что, это требует подключения дополнительной библиотеки к коду.

Comment: Она же std в чем проблема то?

Comment: Первую проблему я описал, это подключение библиотеке и не важно что это вошло в стандарт если я правильно понял ваше сокращение std.
вторая причина была в том что я не нашел как можно используя filesystem создать путь к папки мои документы в windows в итоге я начал использовать SHGetKnownFolderPath

Comment: вы пользовались поиском? есть примеры кода с попытками найти путь до указанных директорий?

Comment: Я искал в поиске гугл и ничего не нашел, сейчас я использую такой способ
`if (FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, nullptr, &pszMyDocuments)))`

Comment: К сожалению я не знаком с winAPI для win32 все что мог предложить выше

Comment: Да ничего, пока все равно использовать буду старый метод, но вот мне интересно в чем преимущество filesystem, почему вы считаете что он лучше?

Comment: используя язык C++ я предпочитаю использовать стандартные средства т.к. они проверенны и рекомендуемые (особенно когда говорим о кросс) и особенно в этом помогает использование pedantic

Comment: я не знаю кто такой pedantic и что это, но вас я понял

Comment: Да я так подумал кроссплатформенность лучше, поставил ваш вариант проверки. только вы много лишнего в коде добавили я убрал dir и .c_str

Answer (score 2):

```
int ret = SHCreateDirectory(nullptr, folderName.c_str());

if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS || ret == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS || ret == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
    // файл/каталог успешно создан или уже существует
    wcout << folderName << "\n" << endl;
}
else
{
    // Ошибка создания
}
```

Как было указано, анализируйте коды самостоятельно, в зависимости от конкретных условий задачи:
ERROR_FILE_EXISTS - означает, что файл уже существует и эту ситуацию стоит обработать отдельно

Comment: Ого не знал что так можно

Comment: `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` — скорей всего ошибка, что файл с тем же именем уже существует и его стоит обрабатывать отдельно... читай — с остальными ошибками...

Comment: У меня вопрос ret == обязательно нужно повторять или можно только один раз написать в самом начале а потом просто || ставить

Comment: нужно обязательно повторять